# std::random_device is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11

The `random_device` class is not recognized as part of the `std::` namespace until I include `<bits/stdc++.h>`.

I want to ask you if there is another solution for this, because I don't really want to include all standard libraries for this purpose.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1,5); 
std::cout<<dis(gen);
```

Comment: `#include <random>`?

Comment: [**Don't** include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Note that generally, you will get an answer for this kind of questions on the site *cppreference*: [cppreference::std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good sign, indeed, that you *don't* want to include all the Standard Library header files ([via the ***appalling*** and **non-standard** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` concoction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073))! However, you *do* need to (explicitly) include the headers relevant to the aspects/components of the Standard Library that you actually use.

In the case of the `std::random_device` class (and, also, the other two random-related classes that you use), you will need to include the header that defines those classes, with the following line:

```cpp
#include <random>
```

Also, for the `std::cout` (and related) classes, you will need `#include <iostream>`.

As mentioned in the comments, the [cppreference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is as good a place as any to get a quick guide to which header(s) you need to include for any of the `std::xxxx` classes, although you will soon 'get to know' the relevant headers for the more common Standard Library classes.